# Which SQL query should I use?

Tags: 7, database

I want to get the number of rows where the "value" field is equal to 1, and output its number  and all the `content_id` where  `value_type` is `option` in table `votingapi_vote`. 
the following is my code, but it doesn't work.

```
$result = db_query("SELECT content_id,count(value=1) FROM {votingapi_vote} WHERE value_type = '%s'" , "option");

while ($obj = db_fetch_object ($result)) {
  return $obj->content_id.'<br>'.'$obj->count';
}
```

it showed an error.  when i delete the filed value in the query. it only output one result of `$obj->content_id`/ why? i want to output all the results of $obj->content_id

**ps: now, if i want to get this result.**

1,get the `content_id` and descending  it according to the value(the count of each `content_id` 's value=1 substract the count of  each `content_id` 's value=0 ,each content_id has many value=0 or value=1)

how to write the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, that condition syntax is just wrong, you need to add that as a WHERE condition. Second, if you want the count per content id, you need to group by that.

And third, you need to collect the output in a variable instead of returning it directly.

Something like this:

```
$result = db_query("SELECT content_id, COUNT(*) AS count FROM {votingapi_vote} WHERE value_type = '%s'"  AND value = 1 GROUP BY content_id, "option");

$output = '';
while ($obj = db_fetch_object ($result)) {
  $output .= $obj->content_id.'<br>' . $obj->count;
}
return $output;
```

Comment: how to output the count number? echo $obj->COUNT ? why use group by? thank you

Comment: could i add a substract to the query. i have update the question.thank you

Comment: it doesn't print the $obj->count;? why?

Comment: If you want to print it, replace return with print.

Comment: you misunderstood my meaning. when you print $obj->count. there is no any output? why? thank you

Comment: you can't output the count number of the value=1 in table votingapi_vote

Comment: maybe the $obj->count has output. it's print null, if it print null.is there a way to sum it?

Comment: there is no number behind the $obj->content_id.. $obj->content_id.has output.

Comment: Ah, sorry, you need to give it a name in the query (AS count), updated my code.